# PHP 7 DOMDocument not found

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to run the command `app/console cache:clear` but it gave an error:

> An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowable
> Error: Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php:52

I use PHP 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Installing php5-dom did not resolve my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dom
```

Comment: Do you have xml module for php in your system  ??

Comment: Note that it may be necessary to `sudo service apache2 restart` after installing the package.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu and fixed it doing the following

```
apt-get install php-xml
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

if not as root

Comment: or `php7.0-xml`

Comment: or `php5.6-xml`

Comment: Notice that you also need to restart your webserver for this to take effect: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: I have a similar issue and I did install php-xml but still same error any idea?

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart php7.4-fpm`(replace 7.4 with your version)

Answer (score 12):

Just a minor addition to the answer. I'm using nginx with PHP 7 and php-fpm. You must restart the php-fpm service in order for the updates to work. Restarting nginx alone won't help.