# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found when flush cache in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to flush cache but via terminal in ubuntu , but is showing error
php bin/magento cache:flushPHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magentotwodemo/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:377

Comment: have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395239/class-domdocument-not-found or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668702/php-7-domdocument-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not installed PHP DOM.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dom
```

if you are using PHP 5.6 then use:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dom
```

if still didn't work then check xml is inatalled or not and try

```
apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

Then restart apache and try