# xampp and PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found

Tags: php, xampp, magento2, php-7

I have magento2 installed on xampp (on ubuntu) and when I try to run setup:upgrade I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /opt/lampp/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Xml/Parser.php:35
```

Now, I did see these two questions ( [PHP 7 DomDocument not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668702/php-7-domdocument-not-found) [Class 'DOMDocument' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395239/class-domdocument-not-found) ) 
but they don't really provide a solution since the xampp app does not use my php installed outside of the xampp environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: It appears that your xampp's PHP doesn't have the extension enabled - probably you only need to uncomment it at `php.ini` and reload Apache.

Comment: @OliverMaksimovic, would it be the php.ini in /opt/lampp? ... which extension would it be? I searched for 'xml' in that file and didn't see anything that looks like that extension. Maybe I don't know what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I realized that the php commands I was executing were run by the php installed on the system, and not the one in use by Xampp. Thus installing the php-xml part solved that issue. I resolved all the subsequent errors in the same way. So far, the app is running ok. Granted, a proper, clean LAMP stack would be preferable, but this will do for now.